# Examining a word in gdb prints in decimal instead of hex

Tags: gdb

I am trying to examine some addresses in gdb. It was printing in hex previously but I'm not sure how I changed it. When I enter `x/20 $rsp` the result looks like this:

```
0x7fffffffb060: -20336  32767   -559038737  0
```

Obviously this is not the end of the world since I can manually convert the values if needed but it is pretty annoying. I've tried exiting gdb and restarting but that does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gdb` uses the last specified setting when printing values. To force hexadecimal, append `x`: `x/20x addr`.

Answer (score 0):

faced the same issue, I try to print one byte first and then x/x shows hex values
[image]

or

use x/4bx to display 4 bytes in hex, there is an extra x in the end.

[image]